# Задача на строки - привести к общему

Tags: python, строки

Есть 2 строки, например, `cat` и `concatenate`.
Какое минимальное число букв в сумме надо выбросить из обоих строк, чтобы остатки строк стали равны.

В примере из `cat` ничего выбрасывать не надо, из `concatenate` - 8 букв. Ответ 8.
Буквы можно выбрасывать из любой позиции, но переставлять буквы нельзя.
Предполагается, что задача может быть решена за 10-15 минут.

Кто может подсказать алгоритм, желательно с кодом, желательно на Питоне.

И еще. Есть ли какие-то материалы, курсы, где рассматриваются подобные задачи. Желательно на русском.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Наибольшая_общая_подпоследовательность

Comment: если пройти по этой ссылке, то кода и понятного объяснения там нет. Но в статье имеется другая ссылка 
http://coders.ask-ru.net/алгоритм-поиска-длины-наибольшей-общ/
и там есть и объяснение, и код на Питоне - короткий.

Остался еще подвопрос об  онлайн курсах, где учат решать подобные задачи. Желательно на русском.

Comment: В общем-то, в большинстве книг и курсов по алгоритмам есть раздел "динамическое программирование", и эта задача - одна из классических для его применения

Comment: Спасибо.
**Один** из этих подойдет ?
https://stepik.org/course/217/syllabus  ИЛИ
https://stepik.org/course/53634/syllabus 

Или что-то другое? Тогда что **конкретно**?

Comment: Ну я их не проходил. Общие принципы ДП и несколько задач разбираются - наверное, подойдут.

Answer (score 0):

```
len_str1 = len(str1)
len_str2 = len(str2)
if len_str1 >= len_str2:
    x = len_str1 - len_str2
else:
    x = len_str2 - len_str1
print(f"Ответ: {str(x)} букв}
```

str1 и str2 - строки.

Comment: *Буквы можно выбрасывать из любой позиции, но переставлять буквы нельзя.*

Comment: Данный скрипт находит кол-во букв, которое необходимо выбросить, как указано в вопросе. Цитирую: "Какое минимальное число букв в сумме надо выбросить из обоих строк, чтобы остатки строк стали равны."

Comment: Спасибо, но я, видимо, привел плохой пример.
Вот другой: `каток` и `закатать` => `кат`  Из первого слова выбрасываем 2 буквы, из второго 5. Ответ 7. НО len(закатать) = 8, а len(каток) = 5.

Comment: вы находите разницу длин, а в варианте caRt и concatenate будет еще буква из короткого слова

Comment: Необходимо из одной строки сделать другую верно? И в 1 строке обязательно есть частьо второй?

Comment: см. новый пример и splash58 все правильно написал.

Comment: найти максимальную длину строки, сохраняя только последовательность букв, карандаш страница => рана

Answer (score 0):

В случае если необходимо сделать из 1 строки другую - можно сделать так:

```
str1 = "cat"
str2 = "thisisacat"
if str1 in str2:
    str2 = str2.replace(str1, '')
    res = len(str2)
else:
    str1 = str1.replace(str2, '')
    res = len(str1)
print(f'Ответ: {str(res)}')
```

Comment: каток и закатать => кат    Этот код не сработает

Comment: **1)** Оба ваших ответа неправильные, заслуживают минуса, думаю их лучше удалить. Задача более сложная, классическая, смотрите обсуждение в комментариях к вопросу. **2)** Даже если бы они были правильными, то следовало бы упаковать их в один ответ: "Решение № 1", "Решение № 2" - посмотрите, как делают другие. **3)** Ответы состоящие из одного кода не приветствуются (если они не совсем уж очевидные), желательно добавлять объяснения, комментарии.

Answer (score 0):

1. вот тут [http://coders.ask-ru.net/алгоритм-поиска-длины-наибольшей-общ](http://coders.ask-ru.net/%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89) все есть - с кодом на Питоне
2. пока что сам придумал такое. Наверняка есть дыры, но несколько тестов вполне проходит

```
def nopp(s1,s2):
      r1,t1 = mistr_(s1,s2)
      r2,t2 = mistr_(s2,s1)
      tmp = len(s1) + len(s2)
      if r1 > tmp: r1=tmp
      if r2 > tmp: r2=tmp
      if r1 < r2 : 
        print(t1)
        return r1
      else:
        print(t2) 
        return r2

def mistr_(s1,s2):
  res = 0
  tst=''   # what is common
  for i in s1:
    tmp = s2.find(i)
    if tmp == -1: 
      res+=1 # no
      #print('no=',i,res)
    else:
      tst = tst + i
      res+=tmp # begin of s2 before i
      if tmp+1 == len(s2): s2=''  # s2 is finished
      else: s2 = s2[tmp+1:]       # rest of s2 
      #print('yes=',i,'res=',res,'s2=',s2)
  #print(tst)    
  return (res + len(s2),tst)
```

Comment: "Дыры" есть. Из `'abab'` и `'bbab'` нужно выкинуть 2 символа, а не 4

Comment: согласен - похоже, что надо откатываться к классической рекурсивной версии. Как допилить собственную - см. выше - мне на ум не приходит 


Есть смутная идея, что надо индексы вхождения букв одного слова во второе построить и начинать с буквы с минимальным индексом, но это уже сильно сложнее классической версии получается... и, наверно, смысла нет.

Старожилы. Мне мою неудачную попытку удалять? Или как тут принято ?

Comment: Решение есть решение, удалять не нужно, может кто-нибудь подскажет как его развить, но навскидку, хоть я и не вчитывался - нужно переписывать с использованием методов дп. Не обязательно рекурсивно, можно в цикле с мемоизацией предыдущих результатов. Сложность должна получиться `O(|s1|*|s2|)` и по минимуму с `O(min(|s1|, |s2|))` дополнительной памяти (если без рекурсии)